# If PHP is running on Linux; how to get the specific distribution(Ubuntu, fedora, etc..)?

Tags: php, linux, operating-system, archlinux

I have a PHP script that interacts with OS's CLI, and I'm expecting this script to run on different Linux distributions, so I have to interact with different Linux falvours differently to achieve something, but I couldn't find a way for PHP to differentiate between them.

I've tried using `php_uname('s')` and `PHP_OS` they both return `Linux`; which isn't any useful for me(I was testing on Arch Linux)

I'm asking this question, because -for example- if I wanted to manage a service/daemon in Ubuntu I'll use the `service` command , and in Arch ill be using the `systemctl` command, so without knowing which Linux distro is running my PHP script there's no way I can deal with such problems.

Comment: Have you tried `echo exec("cat /etc/*-release");` ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV I was actually considering this method, but does it work with all(most) Linux distributions?

Comment: I don't know for sure ...

Comment: Why exactly do you ask? Can't you preferably use standard (Posix or LSB) APIs.... and then you don't care about the specific distribution.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I updated my question, please check it out.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found a flexible solution to this issue. Which is by looking-up the release file from the /etc directory(instead of printing what's actually INSIDE the file), so if I'm running this script on Arch Linux, it'll check for `arch-release` file in `/etc` directory, and so on for other Linux distros.

Here's the code:

**IMPORTANT NOTES:**

- PHP won't scan `/etc` directory if you don't modify `php.ini` file and make it allowed to do file operations on it(modify `open_basedir` option, by adding `:/etc/` to the end.)
- The list of recognizable distros in the following code is easily extensible, all you need is the pretty name of the distro(e.g. Ubuntu) and the name of its release file(e.g. `lsb-release`). For a complete list of famous linux distros, [click here](http://linuxmafia.com/faq/Admin/release-files.html).

  ```
  function getLinuxDistro()
      {
          //declare Linux distros(extensible list).
          $distros = array(
                  "Arch" => "arch-release",
                  "Debian" => "debian_version",
                  "Fedora" => "fedora-release",
                  "Ubuntu" => "lsb-release",
                  'Redhat' => 'redhat-release',
                  'CentOS' => 'centos-release');
      //Get everything from /etc directory.
      $etcList = scandir('/etc');

      //Loop through /etc results...
      $OSDistro;
      foreach ($etcList as $entry)
      {
          //Loop through list of distros..
          foreach ($distros as $distroReleaseFile)
          {
              //Match was found.
              if ($distroReleaseFile === $entry)
              {
                  //Find distros array key(i.e. Distro name) by value(i.e. distro release file)
                  $OSDistro = array_search($distroReleaseFile, $distros);

                  break 2;//Break inner and outer loop.
              }
          }
      }

      return $OSDistro;

  }  }
  ```

Answer (score 1):

PHP uname will usually return what `uname` would in console, which is usually the Linux kernel. Since different distributions have different ways of telling their version, I cannot suggest a deffinitive method for all of them, however, have a read at this: http://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/find-linux-distribution-name-version-number/

Combine that with php's `exec`